# Projecting a LibNoise sphere-mapped image on a model

Tags: c#, xna

I've used the .NET port of LibNoise to create a planetary map using its built-in sphere projection.  However, now I want to wrap that texture around a sphere in XNA.  I've got a sphere model, but I know very little about UV wrapping, etc.  It's entirely possible, if not plausible, that the way I've put UV coordinates on my model absolutely will not work with the generated texture.

I've set up a small test project rather than fiddle around in my main game.  It's your basic rotating model project.  I'm using BasicEffect on the model and setting the Texture parameter as my map.  However, all I see is the model with its default diffuse color and no texture.

For your convenience, the full code of the project:

[Game1.cs](http://pastebin.com/czfTTC62)

[PlanetTerrainMap.cs](http://pastebin.com/61TwT9Yv)

Required files:

[sphere.fbx](https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=5ea5c2eaa6cabfe5&sc=documents&uc=2&id=5EA5C2EAA6CABFE5%21112#)

[EarthLookupTable.png](https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=5ea5c2eaa6cabfe5&sc=documents&uc=2&id=5EA5C2EAA6CABFE5%21112#cid=5EA5C2EAA6CABFE5&id=5EA5C2EAA6CABFE5%21296&sc=documents)

Also, I totally recognize that my map does not look like a map.  I can handle that issue later.  I just want to see all that crappy grain noise on the sphere so I can move forward.

Do I need to use a custom shader?  Or do I need a different model?

Comment: `EarthLookupTable.png` link broken

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried opening this in Blender? It's a great way to confirm if the UV coordinates specified in your model line up to the texture that your trying to use. If it's not going to render after it's imported in to Blender, it's highly likely you won't get it to Render in XNA without specifying the mapping yourself.